# to start making coffee with a coffee brewer

Tags: phrase-requests

I'm seeking an expression for getting the coffee brewer started on making a fresh pot so it's clear that the coffee isn't ready yet but will be some time soon.

My native language has an expression for this, that directly translates to "to put coffee over".

I've been going with an English version "to put on coffee" for that, but I've been told repeatedly this is wrong.

Example: "Get up in the morning, put on coffee, and go shower and get dressed. And then sit and enjoy slowly waking up with a fresh cup of coffee."

For the suggestions I've already gotten here and there:

1: "Make coffee" this doesn't really work for me, as it suggest the coffee is ready at the end of the sentence it is in.

2: "Put the kettle on" doesn't work either; there's no kettle involved in the process.

3: try formulating around it; this more often than not makes too cumbersome sentences.

I've searched high and low, and I can't find how native English speakers put this.

For what I need, it doesn't have to be necessarily entirely grammatically correct, just what real people use casually in everyday conversation.

And if there are differences in British English use, and American, and Australian, that would be useful to me, too.

Comment: What about 'put the coffee on' (by analogy with 'put the kettle on')?

Comment: Start the coffee, put the coffee on (as Kate says).

Comment: Or start the brewer.

Comment: In my opinion "put on *the* coffee" would be acceptable, rather than "put on coffee", but Kate's suggestion to "put the coffee on" is much more idiomatic.

Comment: I think "put *some* coffee on" might be the most natural.

Comment: Other possibilities are *Turn on the coffee" or "Turn on the coffee maker."